# Найти упоминание в строке (@) - php

Tags: php

У меня есть строка вида `слова слова слова @user и еще слова`. Как можно узнать, есть ли упоминание (`@user`) в строке, и вывести имя пользователя в этом упоминании (`user`)? Имя пользователя может состоять из букв и/или из цифр.

Comment: Вы хотите заменить подстроку "@user" настоящим именем пользователя?

Comment: @Visman нет, мне нужно просто определить, есть ли упоминание в строке, и если оно есть, то записать имя пользователя из упоминания в другую переменную, и отправить это в бд

Comment: Для большей ясности - строка с упоминанием ( в моем примере "слова слова слова @user и еще слова" ) - это комментарий на сайте, и пользователи при комментаровании сами "упоминают" какого-то другого пользователя

Comment: Задачу надо разбивать на две части: 1. найти и выделить (если есть) имя юзера из сообщения, 2. определить, действительно ли это имя юзера, существующего в базе.

Comment: Ну вторую часть я смогу сам сделать, а вот по первой части прошу у вас помощи :)

Comment: Вам надо дополнить свой вопрос набором символов, которые могут встретиться в именах юзеров.

Comment: @Visman готово.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать функцию `preg_match_all`. Если предположить, что имя пользователя может содержать буквы, цифры и знак подчеркивания, то задачу можно решить так:

```
$str = "слова слова слова @user и еще слова";
$users_found = preg_match_all('/\@([0-9A-Za-z_]+)/', $str, $matches);

if ($users_found > 0) {
    // $matches[1] содержит массив с именами пользователей
    var_dump($matches[1]);
}
```

Подробнее: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: '/\@([0-9A-Za-z_]+)/' == '/\@(\w+)/'

Comment: Окей, а если кто то просто так поставит "@" (без упоминания какого-то пользователя), то ваш скрипт засчитает это за упоминание?

Comment: Ваш комментарий подозрительно смахивает на "сделай за меня"

Comment: @ilyaspark, прочитайте про квантификаторы https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.9A.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.B8.D1.84.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D1.8F_.28.D0.BF.D0.BE.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.BA_.D0.BF.D0.BE.D1.81.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.B4.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.B9.29

Comment: @Visman, насчет `\w+` согласен. Но в учебных целях `[A-Za-z0-9_]+` мне кажется нагляднее.

Comment: @ilyaspark, а вы попробуйте ;)

Comment: Оу, спасибо, ребят, всё работает отлично)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev всё работает, спасибо :)